# Creating document library through visual studio for SharePoint 2013

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, sharepoint

I am trying to create document library using C# in visual studio for SharePoint 2013. But on running my application I am getting this error "**Microsoft SharePoint is not supported in 32-bit process. Please verify that you are running in a 64-bit executable."** at  this part of the code **using (SPSite site = new SPSite(siteUrl))**. What can be the possible solution for this??

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have a 32-bit machine. SharePoint requires a 64-bit environment. See [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262485.aspx).

Comment: I have checked my system is a 64 bit one. SharePoint has been working fine but there is something specific with this code.

Comment: It seems you'll have to reset your executable/dll to x64-environment. What kind of project are you creating? In the Solution-Explorer, right-click on your project-folder, select properties and look under configuration. Either see "Any CPU" or try to set it to x64.